# when we do a checkout in SVN , is there a order to setting

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

when we do a checkout in SVN , is there an order to setting like 
first  get trunk , after get branch after get tags
please have you this information 
by advance 
thank you

Answer (score 4):

The terms `trunk`, `branch`, `tags` are actually meaningless in Subversion (though some tools may make assumptions based on common directory names like 'trunk').  They are all simply directories in your Repo.  You can grab all, none, or some of them in any order you wish.

Whatever you are trying to achieve will determine which of these you pull down.

Comment: thank you ray for your return ,
what i want to ask , there  is one file in svn parameter ? that we can change it  for we can create  a personally rule for perfoming a checkout ?